# C# retrieve app.config setting base on comboBox selection

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, combobox, app-config

I will need to modify the following C# program to read all of the three letters abbreviationthe country name from config.app and list it on winForm comboBox, and making selection from comboBox to update the `lbCountry.Text` and `lbCurrencyRate.Text` accordingly.
I am new on C#, not sure how to update app.config with the following details and retrieve them base on the selection of comboBox. Hope someone can help.

Country Abbr: USA
Country Name: United States of America
Currency Rate: 1.00

Country Abbr: AUS
Country Name: Australia
Currency Rate: 0.80

Country Abbr: GBR
Country Name: United Kingdom
Currency Rate: 0.76

Country Abbr: JPN
Country Name: Japan
Currency Rate: 113.00

Following are the partial code that was originally created to retrieve one country details from app.config.

```
    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string countryName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("COUNTRY_NAME");
        string currencyRate = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CURRENCY_RATE");

        lbCountry.Text = string.Format("Country Name: {0}", countryName.ToString());
        lbCurrencyRate.Text = string.Format("Currency Rate: {0}", currencyRate.ToString());

        ......
    }
```

App.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="COUNTRY_NAME" value="United States of America" />
        <add key="CURRENCY_RATE" value="1.00" />
      </appSettings>
      ......
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Better to store in separate xml .

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ramankingdom it's better to store the data in an .xml file and read  using the XDocument class.
Or you can store  data in an .csv file and read with third party library like CsvHelper.

Comment: Is that possible to do it in app.config rather than separate xml? if so, is there any example code as I am not sure how to do it in app.config and retrieve from comboBox?